# Alternative to console.log in AWS Lambda

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

I have developed a **lambda function in Node.js.** Currently am using **console.log** to for logging my application logic.

As expected the output of console.log is available in my **AWS Cloud Watch event log.**

Is there any alternative logging mechanism available for AWS Lambda functions ?

Comment: why do you want an alternative?

Comment: For my enterprise application we used [winston logger](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston). So I wants to know any libraries available to log AWS Lambda rather than using console.log.

Comment: Questions asking for resource/library recommendations are not on topic for Stack Overflow.   However... it seems like you should be able to use winston logger in Lambda, if that's what you want -- just not for *logging to files* because there isn't a persistent place for the files to be written (since the containers are ephemeral).  It sounds like you'd need to use an alternate [community contributed transport for winston](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston/blob/master/README.md#transports).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can ship your logs to an ELK stack you run on a EC2 instance.

You can setup a rule in CloudWatch Events that invokes a subscribe-log-group on a Lambda function to setup the subscription of new Log Groups.

Answer (score 1):

The docs points squarely at `console.log` and its variants, without hinting at alternative logging interfaces.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-prog-model-logging.html

> #### Logging (Node.js)
>
> Your Lambda function can contain logging statements. AWS Lambda writes
>   these logs to CloudWatch. If you use the Lambda console to invoke your
>   Lambda function, the console displays the same logs.
>
> The following Node.js statements generate log entries:
>
> - `console.log()`
> - `console.error()`
> - `console.warn()`
> - `console.info()`
>
> For example, consider the following Node.js code example.
>
> ```
> console.log('Loading function');
>
> exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {
>     //console.log('Received event:', JSON.stringify(event, null, 2));
>     console.log('value1 =', event.key1);
>     console.log('value2 =', event.key2);
>     console.log('value3 =', event.key3);
>     callback(null, event.key1); // Echo back the first key value
>
> };
> ```
>
> The screenshot shows an example  Log output  section in Lambda
>   console, you can also find these logs in CloudWatch. For more
>   information, see Accessing Amazon CloudWatch Logs for AWS Lambda.